# In query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on Entity frame work, i have created a method which is returning List of my Table,
I am retrieving data on base of grpID(which is foreign key, so i can have multiple records)
I have saved these grpID's in an array so I want to run IN command on Entity framework so that i can get records in single List, How can i apply In command,my code is below

```
 public List<tblResource> GetResources(long[] grpid)
        {
            try
            {               
                return dataContext.tblResource.Where(c => c.GroupId == grpid && c.IsActive == true).ToList();//This code is not working as i am having array of groupIds

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                
                return ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Contains to mimic something like `Select IN` query

```
dataContext.tblResource.Where(c=> gripid.Contains(c.GroupId) 
                                  && c.IsActive == true)
                       .ToList();
```

where `grpid` is your array of IDs.

You may consider the following example. Suppose you have Product class with two properties ID and Name, and array of ProductList containing the IDs. The Select IN Query should be something like:

```
int[] productList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products.Add(new Product { ID = 1, Name = "Test" });
products.Add(new Product { ID = 2, Name = "Test" });
products.Add(new Product { ID = 6, Name = "Test" });
var myProducts = from p in products
                 where productList.Contains(p.ID)
                 select p;
var methodChainingQuery = products.Where(c => productList.Contains(c.ID));
```

Comment: thanks for reply,but i am having long array, so i can't apply Contains :(

Comment: you can apply `Contains` with `long` data type. :) it is not just for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**IEnumerable.Contains**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) with group id array.

```
List<tblResource> GetResources(long grpid)
{
     try
     {               
         return dataContext.tblResource.Where(c => grpIDArray.Contains(c.GroupId)
         && c.IsActive == true).ToList();    
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {                
          return ex;
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for reply,but i am having long array, so i can't apply Contains :(

Comment: Did you try?, You can apply to long as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
dataContext.tblResource.Where(c=> gripid.Any(GroupId) 
                                && c.IsActive == true).ToList();
```